# How to use swift struct as property in Objective-c protocol?

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift2

I have Objective-c protocol. In this protocol I need to declare a property which is type of Swift struct. How to achieve this to work?

SomeObjectiveCProtocol.h:

```
@protocol SomeObjectiveCProtocol <NSObject>
    @property (nonatomic, readonly) SomeSwiftStruct swiftStruct;
@end
```

Is something like this even posible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figure it out with forward declaration of protocol. I defined

SomeSwiftProtocol.swift:

```
protocol SomeSwiftProtocol {
    // some protocol requirements
}
```

SomeSwiftStruct.swift:

```
struct SomeSwiftStruct: SomeSwiftProtocol {
    // SomeSwiftProtocol implementation
}
```

and than in SomeObjectiveCProtocol.h:

```
@protocol SomeSwiftProtocol;

@protocol SomeObjectiveCProtocol <NSObject>
    @property (nonatomic, readonly) id<SomeSwiftProtocol> swiftStructProtocol;
@end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the protocol [`_ObjectiveCBridgeable`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/protocol/_ObjectiveCBridgeable/) to convert a Swift struct to an Obj-C class. See this example (I haven't tested this yet):

[Easy Cast With _ObjectiveCBridgeable](http://nshint.io/blog/2015/10/07/easy-cast-with-_ObjectiveCBridgeable/)